# Why does ldd show this dynamic linker location?

Tags: dynamic-linking

Here's the link command.  Notice the specially defined dynamic linker near the beginning.

`time gcc -Wl,-rpath,/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib -Wl,-rpath,/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/Macaulay2/armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu-12.04/lib -L/root/M2/M2/libraries/final/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3 -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabi -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../lib -L/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../.. timestamp.o ../d/M2inits.o ../d/startup.o ../d/../regex/regex.o ../d/gmp_init.o ../d/gmp_aux.o ../d/main.o ../d/pari-c.o ../d/M2-factory.o ../d/M2types.o ../d/scclib.o ../d/M2lib.o ../d/M2mem.o ../d/gdbm_interface.o ../d/xml-c.o   ../d/arithmetic.o  ../d/atomic.o  ../d/M2.o  ../d/system.o  ../d/strings.o  ../d/varstrin.o  ../d/strings1.o  ../d/errio.o  ../d/vararray.o  ../d/ctype.o  ../d/nets.o  ../d/varnets.o  ../d/interrupts.o  ../d/pthread0.o  ../d/stdiop0.o  ../d/gmp.o  ../d/engine.o  ../d/xml.o  ../d/stdio0.o  ../d/parse.o  ../d/expr.o  ../d/stdio.o  ../d/stdiop.o  ../d/err.o  ../d/gmp1.o  ../d/tokens.o  ../d/getline.o  ../d/lex.o  ../d/parser.o  ../d/binding.o  ../d/basic.o  ../d/convertr.o  ../d/common.o  ../d/util.o  ../d/struct.o  ../d/classes.o  ../d/buckets.o  ../d/equality.o  ../d/hashtables.o  ../d/sets.o  ../d/version.o  ../d/evaluate.o  ../d/mysqldummy.o  ../d/pthread.o  ../d/actors.o  ../d/actors2.o  ../d/actors3.o  ../d/actors4.o  ../d/xmlactors.o  ../d/actors5.o  ../d/threads.o  ../d/pari.o  ../d/interface.o  ../d/interface2.o  ../d/texmacs.o  ../d/interp.o ../e/error.o ../e/table.o ../e/exptable.o ../e/monordering.o ../e/complex.o ../e/rand.o ../e/matrix-stream.o ../e/cra.o ../e/aring-zz-flint.o ../e/aring-RRR.o ../e/aring-tower.o ../e/aring-m2-gf.o ../e/aring-promoter.o ../e/aring-glue.o ../e/aring-zzp.o ../e/aring-gf.o ../e/aring-ffpack.o ../e/aring.o ../e/schurSn.o ../e/schur2.o ../e/spair-heap.o ../e/dpoly.o ../e/tower.o ../e/interreduce.o ../e/gb-test1.o ../e/finalize.o ../e/NAG.o ../e/overflow.o ../e/memory-status.o ../e/exceptions.o ../e/imonorder.o ../e/sagbi.o ../e/monideal-minprimes.o ../e/dmat-LU.o ../e/lapack.o ../e/LLL.o ../e/fractionfreeLU.o ../e/ntl-interface.o ../e/fplll-interface.o ../e/mat.o ../e/dmat.o ../e/smat.o ../e/coeffrings.o ../e/Eschreyer.o ../e/gbweight.o ../e/qring.o ../e/polyquotient.o ../e/poly.o ../e/debug.o ../e/comp.o ../e/comp-gb.o ../e/comp-gb-proxy.o ../e/comp-gb-declared.o ../e/comp-res.o ../e/res-a0.o ../e/res-a0-poly.o ../e/res-a1.o ../e/res-a1-poly.o ../e/res-a2.o ../e/reducedgb.o ../e/reducedgb-field.o ../e/reducedgb-marked.o ../e/reducedgb-field-local.o ../e/reducedgb-ZZ.o ../e/montable.o ../e/montableZZ.o ../e/schorder.o ../e/GF.o ../e/ZZ.o ../e/QQ.o ../e/RRR.o ../e/CCC.o ../e/assprime.o ../e/buffer.o ../e/comb.o ../e/det.o ../e/frac.o ../e/franzi-brp.o ../e/freemod.o ../e/gb-default.o ../e/gb-homog2.o ../e/gb-sugarless.o ../e/gb-toric.o ../e/gb-walk.o ../e/gbring.o ../e/gauss.o ../e/hermite.o ../e/hilb.o ../e/int-bag.o ../e/intarray.o ../e/matrix.o ../e/matrix-con.o ../e/mem.o ../e/monideal.o ../e/monoid.o ../e/monomial.o ../e/ntuple.o ../e/polyring.o ../e/pfaff.o ../e/relem.o ../e/ring.o ../e/ringmap.o ../e/schur.o ../e/skew.o ../e/skewpoly.o ../e/solvable.o ../e/spair.o ../e/text-io.o ../e/varpower.o ../e/weylalg.o ../e/ZZp.o ../e/interrupted.o ../e/newdelete.o ../e/ntl-internal.o ../e/ntl-debugio.o ../e/matrix-kbasis.o ../e/matrix-symm.o ../e/matrix-sort.o ../e/ring-vecs.o ../e/res-a2-gb.o ../e/engine.o ../e/x-aring.o ../e/x-monom.o ../e/x-monoid.o ../e/x-relem.o ../e/x-free.o ../e/x-mat.o ../e/x-gb.o ../e/x-ringmap.o ../e/x-mutablemat.o ../e/franzi-gb.o ../e/franzi-interface.o ../e/x-monideal.o ../e/x-factor.o ../e/f4/f4.o ../e/f4/f4-syz.o ../e/f4/f4-mem.o ../e/f4/f4-monlookup.o ../e/f4/f4-types.o ../e/f4/f4-computation.o ../e/f4/f4-spairs.o ../e/f4/f4-m2-interface.o ../e/f4/hilb-fcn.o ../e/f4/monhashtable.o ../e/f4/monsort.o ../e/f4/moninfo.o ../e/f4/ntuple-monomial.o ../e/f4/varpower-monomial.o ../e/f4/gausser.o  ../system/m2file.o ../system/supervisor.o ../system/tests.o  ../kernel/bibasis/bibasis.o ../kernel/bibasis/allocator.o ../kernel/bibasis/launcher.o ../kernel/bibasis/monom.o ../kernel/bibasis/monomDL.o ../kernel/bibasis/monomDRL.o ../kernel/bibasis/monomLex.o ../kernel/bibasis/settings-manager.o  -L../d -lM2inits2  -lfac -lcf -lfac -lcfmem -lgc -lpthread -lmpfr -lfrobby -lpari -lmpirxx -lmpir  -Wl,-Bstatic  -Wl,-Bdynamic  -lxml2 -lz -lm -llapack -lblas -lntl -lgdbm -lgc -lreadline -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lstdc++ -lncurses -Wl,-Bstatic  -lgfortran -Wl,-Bdynamic  -ldl -lrt -lm -lxml2 -lm -lc -o "/root/M2/M2/StagingArea/armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu-12.04/bin/M2".tmp`

Here's what ldd has to say about the resulting executable:

```
ldd /root/M2/M2/StagingArea/armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu-12.04/bin/M2.tmp
    libpthread.so.0 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x401b2000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x401cd000)
    libm.so.6 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libm.so.6 (0x40023000)
    liblapack.so.3gf => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/liblapack.so.3gf (0x4029b000)
    libntl-5.4.2.so => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libntl-5.4.2.so (0x40925000)
    libgdbm.so.3 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libgdbm.so.3 (0x4009c000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x400f0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x4008f000)
    librt.so.1 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/librt.so.1 (0x400ca000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x40a3f000)
    libc.so.6 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libc.so.6 (0x40ae6000)
    /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x400aa000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x400d8000)
    libz.so.1 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libz.so.1 (0x40120000)
    libblas.so.3gf => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libblas.so.3gf (0x40138000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libgfortran.so.3 (0x40bc8000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libgmp.so.10 (0x40c43000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0x40c8d000)
```

Why does everything point to `/data/data/...` EXCEPT the dynamic loader itself?

If you want to reproduce the whole thing, it's a [Macaulay 2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/) build on ARM with this `configure` command:

```
./configure  --enable-download --enable-build-libraries=pari --prefix=/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files LDFLAGS=-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `ldd` is actually a script that calls `/lib/ld-linux.so.3` with the executable as argument and `LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1` in its environment, so
`/lib/ld-linux.so.3` reports itself as the dynamic linker.

Instead, you can run

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /root/M2/M2/StagingArea/armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu-12.04/bin/M2.tmp
```

directly, in which case that will be the dynamic linker that you specified that will dump the libraries and itself.

Comment: The loader is in the `.interp` section of an ELF binary, check with `readelf -l M2.tmp` or `objdump -s -j .interp M2.tmp`, especially useful for cross-compiles when your build host cannot run the binaries. Similarly, the `.dynamic` section (indirectly) lists the dynamic libraries (in `.dynstr`), use `readelf` for that too (it chases the links and prints the library names, `objdump` just gives the offsets).

Comment: Yes... that gives me the output I expected!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The arguments:

```
-Wl,-rpath,/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib 
-Wl,-rpath,/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/Macaulay2/armv7l-Linux-Ubuntu-12.04/lib
```

are getting passed to the linker from `gcc`. These are what's driving the `/data/data` in your final binary build.

These switches:

```
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

are controlling where to find the dynamic loader. Double check that this path:

```
/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

is an actual file and not a link to `/lib/ld-linux.so.3`. At least according to the `ldd` output:

```
/data/data/org.freesoft.Macaulay2/files/lib/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0x400aa000)
```

it would appear to be a link.

Comment: I double checked it.  It's not a link.  Everything slm says is right, but Stephane Chazelas has the explaination for ldd's behavior, I think.

Comment: @BrentBaccala - yeah StephaneChazelas knows things that no other human on the planet knows. I never knew that was a script either 8-).