# Why do I have to put -Wl,--dynamic-linker flag if it points to same location

Tags: c++, linker

Yes, I know about [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88819/why-does-ldd-show-this-dynamic-linker-location) but this is not a duplicate.

I try to run my app in an older system where **glibc 2.12** is installed. What I need is **glibc 2.19** and I have installed it and I give its location as **rpath**. Fine! But there is a special case with **ld-linux.so.2** and I want to understand what is going on.

My app finds every thing it needs in **rpath** except **ld-linux.so.2**. When I check with `ldd` I see that it insists to locate it from the system:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002ca000)
```

This makes my app not working with this error:

```
relocation error: /usr/local/lib32/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux.so.2 with link time reference
```

Then, I give this flag to linker to use my own dynamic-linker and not from the system:

```
-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/local/lib32/ld-linux.so.2
```

When I check again with `ldd`, I see that finally it points to the same **ld-linux**:

```
/usr/local/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002ca000)
```

Normally `/usr/local/lib32/ld-linux.so.2` is not pointing to `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, it points to `ld-2.19.so`, and `ld-2.19.so` is not a link, it is the lib itself to use.

Finally, although `ldd` shows me that in these two cases it uses the same `ld-linux.so.2`, **my app do works** in the second case!

What I would expect is that in the second case `ldd` shows me this:

```
/usr/local/lib32/ld-linux.so.2 => /usr/local/lib32/ld-2.19.so
```

What is going on? Does `ldd` shows me the same, but then in the second case in runtime, it locates to where I would expect?